# Insert a Matrix in a Latex Table

Tags: tables, matrices

How can I include a matrix as a value in a Latex table? For example, in the code provided below, I need C to be written in matrix format with the brackets.

```
@code
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{c c c} 
\hline % inserting line
 A & B & C
\\ [0.1ex] 
\hline % inserts single-line
\\ [0.2ex] 
% Entering 1st row
\raisebox{1.5ex}{4} & \raisebox{1.5ex}{3}&\raisebox{1.5ex}{[00; 11; 10;  01]}
\\[0.2ex]
\hline % inserts single-line
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:PPer}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is not really clear, how your matrix should look like. Maybe you can post a little drawing. Thanks. PS: please sign in for this site as well (with your StackOverflow Single Sign On). Like this you will be able to vote on answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like one of these?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{ccc} 
        \toprule
        A & B & C\\
        \midrule
        $4$ & $3$&$\begin{bmatrix}00\\11\\10\\01\end{bmatrix} [00; 11; 10;  01]$\\
        $[00; 11; 10;  01]$ \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:PPer}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use a \savebox to overcome the & conflict between tabular and array.

Comment: Never mind, not needed.  (But the \savebox option does work.)

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks, but I am still waiting for some feedback. Don't know, what the OP actually wants.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi you answered my question, I needed it to be in bmatrix format